# How do I get the name of the variable?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to return some values using sqlite database with the following code:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetRegistry()
    {
        var table = this.connection.Table<Registry>();
        Dictionary<string, string> RegistryItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in table)
        {

        }
    }
```

Given that `var item` represents an sql table item, so saying `item.Age` will be an age and so on. I want to be able to return a dictionary where i can do something like this:

```
Dictionary registry = this.GetRegistry();
int myAge = registry["Age"];
```

What should I do within the `foreach` clause to make this happen?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using C# 6 I think you can do `nameof(item.Age)` to get "Age" back. But something tells me the column name should already be in your object...

Comment: you want to iterate through each column of the table?

Comment: yes i cant do nameof(item.Age) because its a loop, the name of the column is dynamic

Comment: in php i can do `foreach ($array as $key => $value) {}` and `$key` represents the name of the column

Answer (score 0):

Given that table means sql table you could do something like:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetRegistry()
        {


            var table = this.connection.Table<Registry>();
            Dictionary<string, string> RegistryItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var ages = table.Select(X => x.Name == "Age").ToList();

        }
```